# How to search for a specific nested node value in a realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I want to know if there is a certain valued node present in a nested node in a real-time database .
I have attached the screenshot of the structure of the same .
any help is appreciated .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heoAs.png)

i have tried to code it below way but seems it is not right .

```
private boolean checkForSave(String UID){
    boolean found = false ;
    DatabaseReference mRealtime = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mRealtime.child(DatabaseKeys.users).child(UID).child(DatabaseKeys.imgInfo).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot innerValues : snapshot.getChildren()){
                String currentUrl = innerValues.child(DatabaseKeys.imgURL).getValue(String.class) ;
                if(url.equals(currentUrl))
                    found = true ; // getting error in this line , found is not recognizable here
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            throw error.toException() ;
        }
    });

    return found;
}
```

Comment: There is no way you can do that. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to see how can you solve this using a callback. You might also be interested in reading this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5).

Comment: I see  , anyway thanks for the response .